# Strophe Message Sent Acknowledgment Issue

Tags: javascript, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I have implemented OPENFIRE with XMPP + BOSH on my Web based client interface.
When i am sending the message ,i check whether connection is live or not.If it is not live i create new connection and then send.

Sometimes it happens that client send a message and it is not get delivered to **server**(not opposite client).
So for that i need a strong thing that should inform client that this message didn't reach to server,please send again.

```js
try { // sleep(2000);
    Gab.connection.send(message); >
    **var request = $msg({
        to: jid,
        "type": "get",
        id: mid
    }).c('get', {
        'xmlns': Strophe.NS.DISCO_INFO,
        'id': mid
    });**
    console.log(request); >

} catch (err) {
    alert("Internet Disconnected ! Click ok to Reconnect SEND");
    window.top.location.reload(1);
}
```

On above code i call message send().After that i call function as mentioned in "XMPP:xep-0184" doc.
but no response i received.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what a "strong thing" is, but when someone is disconnected in Strophe, you should get errors from the script and it will update the Strophe.Status connection state. Strophe sends a post every 60 secs (unless otherwise specified). In your code it appears you're trying to check support.

You should look for "Strophe.Status.CONNECTED" or "Strophe.Status.ATTACHED" prior to sending if that's your concern. You can also write a handler to manage the errors.

In XEP 0184, you must include:

`<request xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts'/>`

So your msg should look like (note, you must include an id per XEP 0184):

```
$msg({
to: tojid,
from: fromjid,
type: "chat",
id: "sometrackingid"}).c('body').t("bodytxt").up().c("request", {
xmlns: "urn:xmpp:receipts"});
```

You will then need to modify you message handler or create a separate handler to manage the receipts.

Comment: I always check before sending message below conditions.

Gab.connection.connected==false || Gab.connection.authenticated==false
My web page do not get come to know about when it lost connection.So when ever user try to send message i check if connection is there or not.

Some times that happens that my connection got lost and message sent successfully and never reach to server and end user.
In this case it did not show me any error or warning.
My  Client Idle Connections Policy set to 5 Seconds.

Comment: That is why i am trying to figure out ,is my message successfully sent to server or not ??

Comment: 5 seconds is an extremely short timeout period. Is this over a normal website setup? I'm running a site with a thousand connected users with the normal timeout (60 secs) and not having any connection issues. I think  you need to look closer at why your connections are getting lost so frequently.

Comment: I found new issue is ,when i refresh my page and it get double session in my openfire panel.
No. of refresh * number of users = list of sessions in list.

Comment: Store the rid & sid and detect if they exist, then use attach instead on connect when refreshing/changing pages if they exist.

Comment: i have main window.in that 10 chats are allowed.So i load 10  iframe for 10 chats.Every iframe having individual "gab.js" and "strophe.js",So when i reload page then it reinitialize all variables of js file and make another connection with different resource names.